# JavaFX 8 WebEngine: XPath doesn't work

Tags: java, xpath, javafx-8

I have this application that show a web page and print on standard output the result of a XPath search. But I get always an empty `NodeList`, even with differents queries and urls.

Any suggestion?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;


public class TestXPath extends Application {

    private static final String URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath";
    private static final String XPATH = "//span[@class='mw-headline']";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        WebView browser = new WebView();
        browser.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
                (obj, ov, nv) -> {
                    if (nv == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                        try {
                            XPathExpression expression = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile(XPATH);
                            NodeList list = (NodeList) expression.evaluate(browser.getEngine().getDocument(), XPathConstants.NODESET);
                            System.out.println("Elements: " + list.getLength());
                            for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
                                System.out.println("Item " + i + ": " + list.item(i));
                            }
                        } catch(XPathExpressionException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
        stage.setScene(new Scene(browser));
        stage.show();
        browser.getEngine().load(URL);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Most probably you were hit by this bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090173